# python 2.7 if statement gives false output for 0.05 == 0.05

Tags: python, python-2.7

For my assignment I have to check if a calculated value is within 0.05 of 0.5. To do this i thought subtracting one from another, taking the absolute value and checking if that is smaller or equal then 0.05 should do the trick. However when i try this piece of code.

```
x = abs(0.5 - 0.55)

if x <= 0.05:
    print 'x is', x, 'x = yes'
else:
    print 'x is', x, 'x = no'

y = abs(0.4 - 0.45)

if y <= 0.05:
    print 'y is', y, 'y = yes'
else:
    print 'y is', y, 'y = no'
```

The returns a very weird output.

```
x is 0.05 x = no
y is 0.05 y = yes
```

Where y is seen as 0.05 but x is not seen as 0.05, however both values are equal to 0.05 according to python.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: check your conditions before you use them  0.5 - 0.55
Out[1]: -0.050000000000000044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x = abs(0.5 - 0.55)
>>> x
0.050000000000000044
>>> y = abs(0.4 - 0.45)
>>> y
0.04999999999999999
```

This is just how floats behave. [Most programming languages are like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588029/9348376) Usually when comparing floats, its safer to check whether within an allowed error of your value, instead of checking for equality:

```
>>> x = abs(0.5 - 0.55)
>>> allowed_error = 0.000001
>>> abs(x - 0.05) <= allowed_error
True
```

Python3.5 adds the relevant [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose).

Comment: I had no idea, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

By default it's generating long floating value

**Try this:-**

```
x = round(abs(0.5 - 0.55),2)
y = round(abs(0.4 - 0.45),2)
```

Comment: This works thanks! But still why does the code I wrote work with 0.4 - 0.45, but not with 0.5 - 0.55? Shouldn't they both have a long floating value

Comment: @Hans it worked both r printing true i hope you r familiar with round right...that simple make it round that's it...and hope both output u r getting true right...

Comment: @Hans 0.4 - 0.45 = 0.04999999.... which is approximated to 0.05 by Python. Hence you got it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Decimal in this manner:

```
from decimal import Decimal
x1 = abs(0.5 - 0.55)
x2 = Decimal(abs(0.5 - 0.55)).quantize(Decimal(10) ** -2)

print (x1)
print (x2)
```

Output:

```
0.050000000000000044
Decimal('0.05')
```

Then your tests will work fine.